# In ASP.NET MVC 5, how does the framework knows that a POST request comes from its own webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Allow me to explain in more detail.

I've been learning and testing around with ASP.NET's MVC 5 using Visual Studio 2017. From what I understand, a Controller's "Actions" or methods are mapped according to a route format in "RouteConfig.cs", making all public methods accessible to web requests.

In the case of a simple GET method that returns a View, like this one:

```
// GET: Movies/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

I would only need to enter the correct URL and I have obtained the View.

But in the case of sensible POST actions like deleting a data-entry, how does the controller make sure that the POST request is a valid one that comes from one of its own  Views, instead of an unknown webpage? With the assumption that an action only need to be mapped to a matching route to be called.

Using a code sourced from one of Microsoft's tutorials as an example:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();

    /*
    Bunch of Other GET Actions
    */

    // POST: Movies/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        db.Movies.Remove(movie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    /*
    Bunch of Other GET Actions
    */

}
```

How does this Controller achieve this? If not, how can it be achieved?

Comment: This is all about `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. See that Microsoft Tutorial.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev ok, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the purpose of the Anti-Forgery token, which you're validating by decorating the action method with the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute.  Your view will need to include an anti-forgery token to be validated via the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` `HtmlHelper` method

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, ValidateAntiForgeryToken will do this job.
If a bit more explanation, MVC has its own disciplined that once you create a new controller which name is "MyTest", naming convention is MyTestController. It means if you create a view for MyTest controller, a folder with MyTest should be created under View and where MyTest's views are supposed to be kept.
I hope you would get my explanation.
Enjoy coding !